# React, pagination: dynamic number of items per page based on list height

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, pagination

I want to have a `<ul>` list which automatically paginates whenever it exceeds say 50% of the window height (scrollbar should never appear). That is, whenever a scrollbar would normally appear due to list height exceeding window height, it should dynamically paginate at that point instead, based on how many rendered `<li>` items were actually able to fit within the allotted screen space. If something changes to cause more or less `<li>` items to be able to fit (for example, the user changes font magnification), pagination is re-calculated and re-rendered automatically. Each `<li>` item may have a different height depending on its content.

Could anyone provide a library or toy example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Pagination will require you to write the code for this yourself, since your code will need to be tailored to use your API effectively. However there are some very interesting libraries for dynamically and efficiently rendering list like:

[React Infinite](https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite)

[React Infinite Scroller](https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller)

Comment: Those two libraries seem to be for infinite scrolling, which is almost the opposite of what I want (no scrolling - whenever the scrollbar would normally appear, automatically paginate at that point instead). Do you know of any libraries for this?

Comment: @manavM: any solution to this ? I am stuck in a similar problem.

Comment: @FE_Addict It seems I had misunderstood the original question...if dynamic pagination is what you're after you just need to use something like [react-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate) and then ensure its parameters depend on the height of of your list items...which can be calculated using react-virtualized's [Cell Measurer](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/CellMeasurer.md).